# jaxrs.xsd Validation Error

Tags: spring, cxf, jax-rs

I'm new to CXF REST + Spring. Eclipse indicates that my application-context.xml has **s4s-att-invalid-value error:Cannot resolve jaxrs-common:model as a QName: the prefix 'jaxrs-common is not declared**.    Here is my application-context.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">

  <import resource="classpath:META-INF/cxf/cxf.xml" />
  <import resource="classpath:META-INF/cxf/cxf-servlet.xml" />

  <bean class="org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.JAXRSServerFactoryBean" init-method="create">
    <property name="address" value="/service1"/>
    <property:serviceBeans>
      <ref bean="customerBean" />
    </property:serviceBeans>
  </jaxrs:server>

  <bean id="customerBean" class="demo.jaxrs.server.CustomerService" />
</beans>
```

I realized the jaxrs:server tag is causing this error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jaxrs.xsd found at http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/jaxrs.xsd doesn't validate correctly at the moment, hence the problem you encounter.

As soon as the xsd on cxf.apache.org is fixed, this specific validation error will go away.

PS: the application-context.xml you submitted is also not valid xml, must be a copy paste failure.

UPDATE: jaxrs.xsd is now fixed at cxf.apache.org. You might need to clean your local cache (ie delete the workspace internet cache folder: .metadata.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.internet.cache) and restart eclipse.

Comment: is this something we should report to apache? is there any workaround?

Comment: Do we have any alternatives for jaxrs.xsd?

Comment: That worked for me! - btw: small typo on folder (missing backslash before .plugins).metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.internet.cache